# Plot area's on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a requirement where i have to draw areas on HTML5 canvas, area are drawn using circle,rectangle,polygon tool(This is part of configuration i.e only defining the area's). Later in Dashboard(where the configured area's can be viewed) i want to show small sub area's within the area(dynamically through code), the number of sub area's will not be fixed(but the size of sub area's is fixed assume 20 X 20). I want this sub area's to be plotted in such a way that they fit the best possible in their area's and does not come out of area.Can anyone please tell me the most efficient way of doing this.Please refer to attached image.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery or javascript image map editor tool to do so ..

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?5X9o88Va

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/593037/Image-Map-Editor-Fabric-vs-ImageMapster-and-Virtua

Have a look.

Comment: Thank you amit but this is not what i want.I have to place the smaller images in the area drawn.

Answer (score 0):

You're wanting a "bin packing" algorithm that attempts to fit shapes into your container-paths.

Bin-packing solutions differ based on the shape of the elements to be contained and the shape of the container.

Here is a link to get you started:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem

Your "pack rectangles into circle" and "pack rectangles into rectangle" have already been nicely solved.

Your "pack rectangles in non-primary path" will likely have to be solved using a non-optimum way by dividing your path into sub-containers.  The math for this kind of solution is scary and keeps mathemeticians up late at night.